# qmake post shell encoding (doesn't convert to cp866)

Tags: character-encoding, inno-setup, qmake

I have script, binded to `QMAKE_POST_LINK` in my `.pro` file. So it using `iscc` for creating installer after release build. Some app variables like name, publisher are storing in this `.pro` file and passing as arguments to `iscc` like `iscc "/DName=Мое приложение"`. This variables have cp1251 encoding.

So the problem is that `iscc` gets arguments in wrong encoding (as cp866, not cp1251) and resulting `installer.exe` have wrong characters. How to fix it? Is there any function of `qmake` to convert encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

So idea is to write a header `defines.iss` file with that defines using `qmake`'s `write_file` function and in main `.iss` file write `#include "defines.iss"` on beginnig of file.

**Update**: And there can be another problem with encodings. `.pro` file in `qt5` usually is `utf8` encoded. last versions of `inno setup` support `utf8`-encoded `.iss`, BUT this `.iss` must start with `BOM` character.

So, we must write `BOM` character on the beginnig of `defines.iss`. For that for example open `.pro` file in `Notepad++` as `cp1251` and write:

```
BOM = "п»ї"
write_file(defines.iss, BOM)
write_file(defines.iss, DEFINES_CONTENT, append)
```

in `utf8` encoding `BOM` will be correct.

Sorry for my English. It will great if someone corrects my text :)